# SQL: How to compare two rows from same table where second row is given by first's values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is my SQL Server query which works great, but as you can see I am fetching the same row multiple times. Is there a way to optimise this by doing a SELECT only once? Thanks.

```
SELECT TOP 1 1
FROM some_table
WHERE col1 = @col1
  AND (col2 IN ('N', 'C', 'U') OR 
       col3 != (SELECT t.col3 FROM some_table t 
                WHERE t.id = id AND t.revision_id = revision_id - 1) OR
       col4 != (SELECT t.col4 FROM some_table t 
                WHERE t.id = id AND t.revision_id = revision_id - 1) OR
       col5 != (SELECT t.col5 FROM some_table t 
                WHERE t.id = id AND t.revision_id = revision_id - 1) OR
       col6 != (SELECT t.col6 FROM some_table t 
                WHERE t.id = id AND t.revision_id = revision_id - 1)
      )
```

**Note**: I only need to see only if one such column exists (see `SELECT 1 1`), which is more than likely to give be `1` most times. So I do NOT want to do a join of the table which has millions of rows.

Comment: You may be able to use `LAG()` to get a previous row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have an error with the column names in the subqueries. See  [Qualifying column names in subqueries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-ver16#qualifying)

> column names in a statement are implicitly qualified by the table referenced in the FROM clause at the same level.

So, all of these columns belong to `t`: `t.id=id AND t.revision_id=revision_id-1`

And the query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 1
FROM some_table s
WHERE   col1=@col1
    AND 
        (
            col2 IN ('N','C','U') OR 
            EXISTS(SELECT * FROM some_table where id = s.id
               AND revision_id = s.revision_id - 1 AND
               (col3 != s.col3 OR col4 != s.col4 OR col5 != s.col5 OR col6 != s.col6)
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` here to select multiple columns form a related row.

This is just an approximation of what you need as you haven't supplied any example data and expected results. You *may* need to use a `top (1)` with an appropriate `order by` clause or aggregate *if* the *apply* can return more than one row:

```
select * 
from some_table t
outer apply (
  select col3, col4, col5, col6
  from some_table t2
  where t2.id = t.id AND t2.revision_id = t.revision_id-1
)t2
where col1 = @col1
and (
  col2 IN ('N','C','U') or
    t.col3 != t2.col3 or
    t.col4 != t2.col4 or
    t.col5 != t2.col5 or
    t.col6 != t2.col6
);
```